# SharePoint Online backup restore

Tags: sharepoint-online, backup, restore

For SP Server the max. 100 GB is always mentioned as the size for a sitecollection to be able to be restored from backup. Any body any experience with backup restore in SharePoint Online ? Hard to believe with the current max size 25TB for a SiteCollection, that 100GB is still the max. to be restored from backup. Also I read in the SP Online service description that it is also possible to restore a subsite.

That is also such a story online: that only the whole sitecollection can be restored from backup. Any experience in this case in real life ?

Last point is the backup restoration itself: Is it like a snapshot: data and settings, or only data.

So many ghost stories, my colleagues swears that it is only the data. Find it hard to believe!

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online, we are not allowed to take a backup of one site collection and restore it by ourselves.

To back up and restore site collection in SharePoint Online, you could create an Office 365 support ticket to achieve it.

[Contact Office 365 for business support - Admin Help](https://threewill.com/the-4-options-you-need-to-know-about-sharepoint-online-backup-and-restore/)
More information:

[The 4 Options You Need to Know About SharePoint Online Backup and Restore](https://threewill.com/the-4-options-you-need-to-know-about-sharepoint-online-backup-and-restore/)

Comment: Thanx for the effort Amy. This article (from 2014 !) states nothing about size and type of restoration.